Preventing f10 selecting the menu bar in Python (Windows 10/11)
I admit that ideally I should not be trying to use the f10 as a keypress() in python but I have a program which is used at a miniature railway to track train movements. The signallers select the type of train entering the system using the f keys (1-12) because that is what the visual basic predecessor did.
The program works fine, all of the f keys call a listener piece of code but when f10 is pressed the code freezes and (from googling) I think windows is switching focus to the python application menu bar. Pressing f10 again (or pretty much any key) resumes the program including running the code I set for f10 (irrespective of whether it is f10 pressed twice or another key).
I have tried return "break" but it appears that the menubar is being processed before the keystroke is passed to python and the listener.
def on_release(key): # process to process key strokes based on when key is released
    lastkey=format(key) # format the key released to make it easier to process
    if lastkey[:4]=="Key.": # Test special keys
        lastkey=lastkey[4:] # strip off first 4 characters
        match lastkey:
            case "f10":
                btemp=berth[1][0:2] # read contents of CH11
                if btemp != "2H":
                    ntemp=nextcode[6]+100 # get new number
                    ntemp=str(ntemp)
                    i=0
                    while i<6: # Look through stack for headcode 2H
                        if chstack[i][0:2]=="2H":
                            ntemp=chstack[i][-2:] # store number from headcode
                            j=i
                            while j<5:
                                chstack[j]=chstack[j+1] # move entries down stack
                                j=j+1
                            chstack[5]="    " # blank end of stack
                            i=7
                        i=i+1
                    ntemp="2H"+ntemp[-2:] # create new headcode
                    if i==6:
                        nextcode[6]=nextcode[6]+1 # increase next number
                        if (nextcode[6]>99): # loop next number when reaches 100
                            nextcode[6]=1
                    berth[1]=ntemp # store new headcode in CH11
                return "break"



def on_press(key): # routine to catch key presses (no action taken)
    return "break"

# Set up listener event to asynchronously process key strokes
listener = keyboard.Listener(
    on_press=on_press,
    on_release=on_release)
listener.start()



Any help gratefully received
I have tried using both the laptop keyboard and an external keyboard.

I have been doing a bit more playing and moved the code to on_press - if i press and release the f10 slowly the code is executed and the screen is updated (by other bits of the code). It appears to be the on-release of f10 which is causing the program to freeze and the selection of the menubar.

Which library are you using for keyboard input? Is it a GUI library or is this running in a terminal window?

@DanGetz - I am using the keyboard routines from pynput.
I am running the pyc file from a terminal window and it creates a window (using tkinter) and then displays everything in that window which is the only active window.

Some googling suggests that Microsoft have introduced with Win10 onwards that pressing f10 will change the focus to the menubar of the running application so a different question may be whether it is possible to turn off that "feature".

Frustratingly, the old version of the program written in VBA in Excel does not exhibit the issue -     .OnKey Key:="{F10}", procedure:="SetTime"
works fine :-(

You could try using Tkinter events on the window instead of pynput, but I couldn't say if that would make a difference.
